# MATLAB: how to replace values by another values for each row WITHOUT a loop

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix A made of 1 2 and 3, e.g.,

```
 A= [ 1 2 2 1;
      3 3 1 2;
      ...
      ...
      1 1 2 2]
```

now I want to replace 1 2 3 with different values in B according to its row. e.g.,

```
 B= [  4  5  6;
      10 20 30;
      ...
      ...
      77 88 99]
```

I want to replace the value in A to B in each row. e.g.,

```
 A= [ 1 2 2 1;  replace '1 2 3' with '4 5 6' respectively
      3 3 1 2;  replace '1 2 3' with '10 20 30' respectively
      ...
      ...
      1 1 2 2]  replace '1 2 3' with '77 88 99' respectively
```

C will be the matrix with the new assignments that I want.

```
 C= [  4  5  5  4;
      30 30 10 20;
      ...
      ...
      77 77 88 88]
```

I can't avoid a loop in this case, here is the quickest way that I can do:

```
 for row_i=1:size(A,1)
     C(row_i,:)=B(row_i,A(row_i,:))
 end
```

I hate loops in MATLAB, and the actual size of A and B are large, therefore wonder if anyone can reproduce it without loop will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = [ 1 2 2 1;
      3 3 1 2;
      1 1 2 2];

B = [ 4  5  6;
     10 20 30;
     77 88 99];


C = B(sub2ind(size(col), repmat(1:size(A, 1), size(A, 2), 1).', A));

     4     5     5     4
    30    30    10    20
    77    77    88    88
```

**Explanation**

You're using `A` to indicate which column of `B` to use. And as you said, you want the row to be the same as the row in `A`. So we just need a row and column index into `B` for each member of `A`.

To get the rows, we just need to create a matrix the size of `A` where every element in each row is equal to the row index. Also we take care to avoid any magic numbers and actually determine the proper size.

```
rowindex = repmat(1:size(A, 1), size(A, 2), 1).'

     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3
```

Great, now that we have that, we *already* know the columns. That is simply `A`!

```
 colindex = A

     1     2     2     1
     3     3     1     2
     1     1     2     2
```

Now we just need to convert these subscripts to absolute indices using [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) and the size of `B` as a reference.

```
indices = sub2ind(size(B), rowindex, colindex)

     1     4     4     1
     8     8     2     5
     3     3     6     6
```

Now we just need to use these to index into `B` and assign to `C`.

```
C = B(indices)

     4     5     5     4
    30    30    10    20
    77    77    88    88
```